# Autogenerating schema from NHibernate attribute annotated types

Tags: c#, nhibernate, database-schema

I want to export a schema from my types annotated with NHibernate attributes. Is this possible?

My current code is below, needless to say, it compiles, but the expected table `TestType` does not get created.

I have a type as follows:

```
    [Serializable, Class(Schema = "test")]    
    public class TestType
    {
        [Property]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Property]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

And my export code looks like this:

```
//...
cfg.AddAssembly(Assembly.Load("My.Assembly"));
new NHibernate.Tool.hbm2dd.SchemaExport(NHibernateConfiguration)
                          .Execute(false, true, false); 
//...
```

Comment: I am attempting to generate the schema from fluent mappings, in the absence of further knowledge re attributes.

Comment: so... it's not very clear, do you want to use fluent mappings (fluent nhibernate) or attributes?

Comment: In the end I used attribute mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your NHibernateConfiguration object has been configured correctly with the relevant class mappings, this will work:

```
new NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport(NHibernateConfiguration).Create(false, true);
```

If the class mappings have not been set properly in the NHibernateConfiguration, then there will be no schema to create and hence it will appear the SchemaExport is not working.